# Error with jekyll-sitemap when run rake generate to user jekyll with octopuses

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll, octopress

I am building a blog with octopuses and Jekyll on GitHub with Mac OSX and I followed every step on the octopuses website. Error with sitemap occurred when I run rake generate.

```
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css 
Configuration file: /Users/WangWei/Documents/GitHubPage/octopress/_config.yml
            Source: source
       Destination: public
      Generating... 
Error reading file /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-sitemap-0.6.1/lib/sitemap.xml: No such    file or directory -   /Users/WangWei/Documents/GitHubPage/octopress/source/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-sitemap-0.6.1/lib/sitemap.xml
```

Any one can help?

Comment: did you add "gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap" to your config.yml and gem 'jekyll-sitemap' to Gemfile?

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of jekyll-sitemap and it has already been fixed. You can upgrade jekyll-sitemap to v0.6.2 and everything will be ok. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap/issues/54